# Edit- how can I get UIlabel to get in the middle of the container?

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, transition, auto

how can i get UIlabel to get in the middle of the container? and that text and view disappear equally and come to the next view.

EDIT: This code is working fine for me now

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

let container = UIView()
let redSquare = UIView()
let blueSquare = UIView()
let label = UILabel()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.label.textColor = UIColor.orange

    self.label.font = label.font.withSize(25)
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0

    self.label.center = self.blueSquare.center

    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    self.label.text =

    "sosdihfiosdfhsdhfdisfhsdfhdsoifhsdofhsdifhdsofhdsofhsdohdsfdosdohdfh"


    self.blueSquare.addSubview(label)

    self.label.frame = CGRect(x: 45, y: 120, width: 300, height: 100)

    self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 200, width: 400, height: 500)
    self.view.addSubview(container)
    self.redSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 500)
    self.blueSquare.frame = redSquare.frame

    self.redSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    self.blueSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    self.container.addSubview(self.redSquare)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two labels like:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
```

then inside viewDidLoad() before adding redSquare to container fix some labels's property and add label's to blue and red square:

```
label.center = self.redSquare.center
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
label.text = "same text"

label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
label2.center = self.blueSquare.center
label2.text = "same text"

self.blueSquare.addSubview(label2)
self.redSquare.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: thank you so much, this helped. can you also show a simple code that auto layout will work properly?

Comment: Welcome. Auto layout is a must known thing and you can start from here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started